# How to access Alamofire request parameters inside response closure?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm Working on a little project using Swift 2.0 and Alamofire 3.
I have few parameters that I need to send to server.

```
var myParameters = [
            "myObjectName":"FooBar",
            "myObjectId":123456
        ]
```

To send the data  I have a basic request written with Alamofire

```
let myRequest = Alamofire.request(.POST, MY_SERVICE_URL, parameters: myParameters as! [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)
```

and I'm getting response like this:

```
            myRequest.response { myRequest, myResponse, myData, myError in

            /*
            Here I would like to access myParameters, simply to double-check the ID of the data that I have sent out with myRequest.
            */
            print("I'm Done with sending Object number \(myObjectId).")
        }
```

Is there any simple way to pass myObjectId to response closure? Or access it any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the parameters like this:

```
let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, "", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil)

request.response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
    guard let httpBody = request?.HTTPBody else { return }
    do {
        if let jsonParams = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(httpBody, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let objectId = jsonParams["myObjectId"] {
                print(objectId)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```